# Transfer mp3 files to Nokia Lumia from a Mac?

Tags: mp3, mobile-device-management

On Windows, I use standard software (Zune) to transfer files to my Nokia Lumia 800.

Is there any way to transfer mp3 files from Mac to Lumia? Lumia is running Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Windows Phone 7 Connector](http://itunes.apple.com/mt/app/windows-phone-7-connector/id415571499?mt=12) software, made by **Microsoft** specifically for OS X.

[Download here](http://itunes.apple.com/mt/app/windows-phone-7-connector/id415571499?mt=12)